# Reg expression subset work individually but when in function nothing happens

Tags: regex, r, function

Good evening,

I have a list "a" which I successfully subset using regular expressions.

```
a=a[grep("Macy*|Nors*", a$Geography, perl=TRUE),]
a=a[grep("Levis*|Diesel*|Replay*", a$Brand.Name, perl=TRUE), ]
a=a[grep("Week*", a$Time, perl=TRUE), ]
```

I created the function clean below but when I apply it to my list "a"nothing happens

```
clean=function(x){
x=x[grep("Macy*|Nors*", x$Geography, perl=TRUE),]
x=x[grep("Levis*|Diesel*|Replay*", x$Brand.Name, perl=TRUE), ]
x=x[grep("Week*", x$Time, perl=TRUE), ]
return (x)    
}
```

clean(a) just returns original "a" 
I tried printing each individual step but literally nothing happens.
Thank you for your help

Comment: `x$Geography <- grep("Macy*|Nors*", x$Geography, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: You don't have a regex problem, you have a dollar sign operator problem. Subsetting a dataframe with `x$column` should not be used in functions. It is only a convenience function. You should subset the proper way when writing functions `x[,'column']`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but @AvinashRaj this still doesn't work, I get an error Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Geography", value = c(21308L, 21309L,  :replacement has 18430 rows, data has 123482

Comment: Thank you @PierreLafortune. I tried x=x[grep("Macy*|Nors*", x[,Geography], perl=TRUE),] and I get the following error when I do clean (a)  Error in `[.data.frame`(x, Geography) : object 'Geography' not found

Comment: You have to combine my suggestion with the first `x[,Geography] <- grep("Macy.....`

Comment: @PierreLafortune It's still doesn't work, I believe this is because when I do a[,Geography], I get Error in `[.data.frame`(a, Geography) : object 'Geography' not found
But with a$Geography, I don't get any error and it displays the Geography column from the data frame

Comment: `a$Geography` is equivalent to `a[,'Geography']`. See the difference? Hint: quotation marks

Comment: clean=function(x){
  x[,'Geography']=grep("Macy*|Nors*", x[,'Geography'], perl=TRUE) } but this still gives me the error Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , "Geography", value = c(21308L, 21309L,  : 
  replacement has 18430 rows, data has 123482

Answer (score 0):

```
a = data.frame(Geography = c(paste('Macy',1:5, sep = " "),'john'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

a

      Geography
1    Macy 1
2    Macy 2
3    Macy 3
4    Macy 4
5    Macy 5
6      john

clean = function(x){
x = x[grep("Macy*|Nors*", x[['Geography']], perl = TRUE),]
return(x)    
}

clean(a)
[1] "Macy 1" "Macy 2" "Macy 3" "Macy 4" "Macy 5"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this does nothing to my list a, the same way my 1st attempt x=x[grep("Macy*|Nors*", x$Geography, perl=TRUE),] was doing nothing